# JButton.setIcon() doesn't work

Tags: java, user-interface, background, icons, jbutton

this code doesn't work, the JButton is visible but it doesn't have any image. I've been getting crazy over it the Whole day, i've also tried checking whether or not the image exists with file.exists and it is placed correctly, even with the URL format it doesn't appear help!!

```
    package example;

    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame window=new JFrame("example");
            JPanel panel=new JPanel(null);
            JButton button=new JButton();
            ImageIcon flower=new ImageIcon("redf.jpg");
            button.setIcon(flower);
            window.add(panel);
            panel.add(button);
            window.setVisible(true);
            button.setBounds(50,50,100,100);
            window.setBounds(10,10,400,400);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Likely it's because you're using the wrong path to the image (as happens time and time again in similar questions).

Comment: no, i checked it and duplicated the image in the workspace, in the example project folder and in src, it doesn't show though, i think there might be somethin wrong with my JDK or so... because in my school everyone managed to do it but me